# How to add javascript into SharePoint Online

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm new to SharePoint and I got a request to create a form with some items that get selected previously.

I did some research here and I found a topic: "**Get Selected items in a list SharePoint online**" which is in Javascript,  but doesn't tell how to use that javascript code into SharePoint; could someone point me in the correct direction how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

It was some time that I tried to communicate with SharePoint from a JavaScript frontend, but it was quite tedious.

Is the SP and FE on the same server? In my case they weren't which complicated authentication a lot. There is no "easy" way to authenticate to SP in JavaScript, as there are several validation steps, at least not at the time, so we ended up using a .NET backend. The .NET backend can use the [CSOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code) library to authenticate and communicate with SharePoint (off and on premise). Then expose some REST API functions for the frontend to use.

I hope my experience can be of some help.

Comment: I read few posts where , people just wrap the JS code into HTML and call the HTML code from inside SharePoint Online, but I'm not familiar with the parameters that I should be adding on that wrapper, that why I post the question in here.  Right now I dont have access to .NET, so for now one of my only choices is to figure out if I can use html and JS.     Thanks for your comment anyway.

Comment: If I understand right, you would use some kind of web hooks to facilitate communication between SP Online and frontend JS. I googled SP Online web hooks and found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/overview-sharepoint-webhooks). By skimming it through, certain events can emit POST requests. However, this option as well involves some backend that can subscribe to the POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a JavaScript code into an HTML, or better, you can write a separate external JS file for the same. If you are using a SharePoint 2013 Designer, you can open the site into it to modify or design the pages. In that, there is one folder viz., "Site Assets". In that, you can add a JavaScript file.

Then the JS file file reference can be given in your HTML or aspx code under the "Additional Page Head".

Comment: Thanks for your comment,  I did what you suggested me but I get a blank page.  what do you mean by "Additional Page Head " ?  maybe that is the part that I didn't get it right.   Regards.

Comment: In a simplistic way, this is the html code that I use as my test, before I call the real JS code.   

'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JAVASCRIPT</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script src="/SiteAssets/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </body> 
</html>        
'

from there I called the  script.js file  which only have one line.  


' alert('stay away');  '